# Where can I find information about the instance I have on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I launched an ec2 t1.micro instance on Amazon aws. Then I have successfully ssh into it with the key.pem file they gave me but when I go to aws.amazon.com and go to the instances tab on the left it says I don't have any instances launched. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you are looking in the wrong region.

Look in the upper right hand corner of the aws.amazon.com console webpage, for the region drop-down and make sure you have selected the region in which you know you created your instance.

[image]